# OOP: hierarchical-dependency relation between objects

Tags: php, oop, scope, hierarchy

For a project I'm parsing and merging multiple xml configuration files. These xml configuration defines blocks, which may or may not create output, options which are available throughout the whole system etc. The blocks are hierarchical, which means: a block can hold other blocks.

A (merged) configuration can look like this:

```xml
<block name="root">

    <block name="sub">

        <block name="sub2">
            <option name="some-option" value="some-value" />
        </block>

        <option name="sub" value="value" />
    </block>

    <option name="key" value="value" />
    <remove name="sub" />
</block>
```

As you can see, a block has a scope. Which means: block `sub` is only available  in block `root`, block `sub2` is only available within block `sub`. *But*: the options are available everywhere, *but only if the containing block still exists*. As you see, the last line holds a `remove` 'command', which removes the block `sub` from the tree, as well as it's children (block `sub2` and options `some-option` and `sub`).

**How can I maintain the hierarchical object structure AND hold references to the elements scope?**

I explored the some options, like a hierarchical object structure:

```php
class Block {
    private $parent = null; // reference to parent block, or 'null' if no parent exists
    private $children = array(); // list of children blocks
    private $options = array(); // list of options
    private $removes = array(); // list of remove 'commands'
}
```

Or even a nested-set model (sql pattern with left and right values).

But whatever I try, some problems still arise:

1. "Staging": how can I make available options, removes etc. to the "global scope", but keep track of where they were defined. Eg: the option with the name "some-option" should be available to any part of the system, *unless* it's containing block ("sub2") is removed.
2. "Stacking": I need to store all "remove" options until the whole xml tree is parsed, and only then it should execute all removes. Removes should be executed from the outside-in. Meaning that if in a high-level block (nearer to the root) a remove is found, it should be executed first, maybe deleting a remove directive from a lower-level block. What are my options? For each remove store a reference to it's holding block (eg. `$remove[] = array('what-to-remove' => 'sub2', 'parent' => &$sub)`)?

I hope someone can point me in the right direction! If something is not clear, please comment!

Comment: Does `remove` mean that `sub` should be ignored while parsing xml or it should be removed at runtime? If the latter, actually when it should be removed?

Comment: As it is a merged tree, parsing can't be done in a lineair fashion, as directives like `remove` can be placed virtually everywhere, eg. at the beginning (when the objects to be removed aren't defined yet). And, some directives are of influence to the "global" scope, others only to it's containing block. So removing a `block` can result in removing a `remove` (which in it's turn would've removed another block when it would've been present).

Comment: So yes: although the tree should be parsed as early as possible, it should be executed at the latest possible moment to ensure every directive that could influence another is already available.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a kind of Register class as such :

```
<?php

class Register {

    protected static $_instance;

    protected $_options = array();

    public static function getInstance() {
        if( null === self::$_instance ) {
            self::$_instance = new Register();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    // Assuming your option has a unique name
    public function registerOption( Option $option, Block $owner = null ) {
        $this->_options[$option->name] = array(
            'option' => $option,
            'owner'  => $owner
        );

        // Adds the option to the block if not exists
        if( null !== $owner && !$owner->hasOption($option) ) {
            $owner->addOption($option);
        }
    }

    public function removeOption( $optionName, $removeFromOwner = true ) {
        if( isset($this->_options[$optionName]) ) {
            if( $removeFromOwner ) {
                $owner = $this->_options[$optionName]['owner'];
                if( null !== $owner ) {
                    $owner->removeOption( $optionName );
                }
            }            

            unset( $this->_options[$optionName] );
        }

    }

}
```

When you parse a new option, within a block, you can register it by calling Register::getInstance()->registerOption( $option, $owner )

While you parse your XML, you can stack your remove commands in an array containing option names to remove (assuming option names are unique, you'll maybe have to work around this solution if they are not unique).

Once everything is parsed, you can unstack your remove commands and call removeOption( $optionName ) to remove the option from the register and from the block who owns the option.

Did I forget something ?